Looking for a valid nginx configuration
This is my first time using nginx. I'm trying to simply forward traffic from port 80 to 127.0.0.1:8080 where I have a vapor server running. I've scoured the web looking at configurations for nginx and haven't found a solution yet. I'm using a mac server. Please help. This is what my configuration looks like currently:
server {
        listen         80;
        server_name  192.30.133.70;
            
        #charset koi8-r;
            
        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
    
        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

also:
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
 
    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;


As far as I can tell the change that made the difference was the server name. nginx and my vapor server are working magically. This is what server_name is now:

server_name _;

